# How to fix "crazy keyboard" on Ubuntu 10.04.1 on VMWare Player 3.1.x?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, vmware-player, linux-server

On a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 10.04.1 on VMWare Player 3.1.1, the keyboard mappings are crazy!

The arrows don't work, Ctrl key seems mapped to Enter, it's nuts!

Note, this is a command-line server only, without X-Windows.

The host is Windows 7.

What's the quick and easy fix??

Thanks

Comment: Crazy question: During install did you select the default US keyboard layout?

Comment: I used the automated "easy install" through the VMWare prompts. Was never prompted for a keyboard type.

Comment: Install Ubuntu properly. Download the ISO and install it in a fresh virtual machine.

Comment: Anyone found an answer to this? Having the same problem. http://nthrbldyblg.blogspot.com/2008/06/vmware-and-fubar-keyboard-effect.html Blog suggested all sorts of things, but none of them worked for me! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

> dpkg-reconfigure console-setup

Should work in console.

Use A key to jump to the ACPI standard (since arrow keys are not working), and then TAB, Enter to proceed with the setup. You can leave all other settings on their defaults.

In the end reboot the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Change the layout in preferences.
Using **xmodmap** isn't Ubuntu way.

Comment: What preferences? vi /etc/preferences? or what :-) ?